# Computing $a,b$ with $a^2+b^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

I want to compute a solution of the congruence
$$
a^2+b^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}.
$$
I know that a solution always exists (this is a simple argument using the pidgeonhole principle). I also know that if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and the problem can be solved by calculating a square root $a$ of $-1$ and letting $b=0$.

However, for general $p$, I know of no better method than simply trial and error (which is actually not so bad either since of course the chance to "stumble upon" quadratic residues is about a half). Does anyone know or can anyone think of a more efficient method?

Comment: You are referring to the answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294672/x2y2-1-mod-p-is-solvable-if-p-equiv-3-mod-4) for solvability, right? In Ireland-Rosen's book on number theory they solve it using Jacobi sums for the finite field $\Bbb F_p$. On the other hand, Jyrki's answer is also great, see the duplicate.

Comment: More generally, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573579/algorithm-to-find-solution-to-ax2-by2-1-in-a-finite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) explains how to find all solutions to $ax^2+by^2\equiv -1\bmod p$ in a finite field (replacing $a,b$ by $-a,-b$).